# Applying width NSLayoutConstraint to objects grows from right to left

Tags: ios

I have a UITextField that I have applied a positioning constraint to position it and width constraint to adjust its width. When I set the constant for the with constraint to make the textfield wider it grows from the right to left. I would like it to grow from left to right. It is as if the anchor is set on the right. How do I change this? Thanks

Comment: how did you position it? did you align its right side with something?

Comment: Are you doing this with code or in Interface Builder?

Comment: Sounds like you pinned its trailing edge and not its leading edge?